# What are options hashes?

Tags: ruby, hash, optional-parameters

Will someone please explain options hashes? I am working through the ruby course from testfirst.org. Exercise 10 (temperature_object) requires knowledge of options hashes.

Answer (score 59):

Options hash is a nice concept enabled by a feature of ruby parser. Say, you have a method with some required arguments. Also you may pass some optional arguments. Over time you may add more optional arguments or remove old ones. To keep method declaration clean and stable, you can pass all those optional arguments in a hash. Such method would look like this:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, opts = {})
  opts.to_s # just return a string value of opts
end
```

So it has two required values and last argument with default value of hash. If you don't have any optional arguments to pass, you call it like this:

```
foo(1, 2) # => "{}"
```

If you do have something optional, you call it like this:

```
foo(1, 2, {truncate: true, redirect_to: '/'}) # => "{:truncate=>true, :redirect_to=>\"/\"}"
```

This code is so idiomatic to ruby that its parser actually allows you to omit curly braces when passing hash as a last argument to a method:

```
foo(1, 2, truncate: true, redirect_to: '/') # => "{:truncate=>true, :redirect_to=>\"/\"}"
```

If you use rails, for example, you'll see options hashes *everywhere*. Here, I opened just a random controller in my app:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :prepare_search_params, only: :index
                                    #    ^^^^^^^^^^ options hash here
```

**So, in short**: options hash is argument of a method which is located last and has default value of `{}`. And you normally pass hashes to it (hence the name).

Comment: On a modern version of Ruby, you should really use keyword arguments instead of an options hash.

Comment: @JörgWMittag can you explain?

Comment: @Dennis: `foo(arg1, arg2, truncate: false, redirect_to:)`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20634180/2988) for the whole story.

Comment: @JörgWMittag oh, turns out I knew that - the terms confused me since using the newer syntax would technically still give you an "options hash". Anyway, always good to show an example.

Answer (score 13):

Options hashes are used a lot when need to pass optional arguments to method.

For example, if method has one-two optional args, you can write

```
def method(arg1, arg2 = nil, arg3 = nil)
  ...
end
```

But if you have more optional arg it's getting ugly to assign them to nil every time.
Here comes the options hash which allows you to write

```
def method(arg1, options={})
  @arg1 = arg1
  @arg2 = options[:arg2]
  ....
  @arg15 = options[:arg15]
end
```

Answer (score 7):

An options hash refers to the convention of passing options to methods using a hash (`{}`) like so

```
my_func(arg1, arg2, {:opt1 => 'foo', :opt2 => 'bar'})
```

The convention is for the options hash to be the last argument so that it can be made optional. E.g.

```
def my_func(argument1, argument2, options = {})
   ...
end
```

So an options hash isn't anything special. It's just an optional final argument that is a hash. Options hashes are so handy and common that the interpreter also lets you leave off the braces (this is the one "special" part about them)

```
my_func(arg1, arg2, :opt1 => 'foo', :opt2 => 'bar')
```

Combined with Ruby's Symbol hash key shortcut and optional parentheses, this can end looking really clean:

```
my_func arg1, arg2, opt1: 'foo', opt2: 'bar'
```

Answer (score 7):

Since all these answers are correct, ruby 2 improved the support to keywords arguments.

You can define your method with the default hash params as `*args`, and rid the `options = {}`.

```
def foo(bar: 'initial')
  puts bar
end

foo # => 'initial'
foo(bar: 'final') # => 'final'
```

Required arguments: you need a colon after the key (also you need ruby 2.1)

```
def foo(bar:)
  puts bar
end

foo # => ArgumentError: missing keyword: bar
foo(bar: 'baz') # => 'baz'
```

Optional arguments, you can set the default to `nil`

```
def foo(bar: nil, baz: 'aaa')
  puts "#{bar}:#{baz}"
end

foo # => ':aaa'
foo(baz: 'zab') # => ':zab'
foo(bar: 'rab', baz: 'zab') # => 'rab:zab'
foo(bin: 'bin') # => ArgumentError: unknown keyword: bin
```

Also you can use the standard positional args with this new hash parameters notation. You will find more information at this [blog](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) and at the [oficial](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) documentation.

Bonus: The refactor is easy because you can rid the options hash of your method without change the calls of it. But... this is not completely true, if you have a call with an unexpected option you will get an `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: invalid_arg`.

Answer (score 4):

Reverse Merge is the best way to implement options hashes in ruby/rails:

```
def set_state_application(options_hash)
  options_hash.reverse_merge!(send_email: true, other_default_val: 'a') #will set defaults
  self.update_column(:status_id, VendorEnums::VendorStatus::APPLICATION)
  VendorMailer.email_application(self) if options_hash[:send_email]
  save_state
end
```