# Ruby 2.1.1 ArgumentError when passing hash before keyword arguments

Tags: keyword-argument, ruby-2.1, argument-error

In Ruby 2.1.1 I defined the following method:

```
def post(url, params={}, send_json: false, success_only: true)
```

This is called within the same object in another method `privateToken` like so:

```
    self.post("#{@url}/api/v3/session", {
        :login    => @user,
        :password => @pass,
    })['private_token']
```

However, calling `privateToken` in `initialize` for this object results in:

```
<script>:207:in `privateToken': unknown keywords: login, password (ArgumentError)
    from <script>:199:in `initialize'
    from <script>:575:in `new'
    from <script>:575:in `<main>'
```

If I change the `post` method to accept `params` as a keyword argument then this error is avoided:

```
def post(url, params: {}, send_json: false, success_only: true)

# ..then in method 'privateToken':
self.post("#{@url}/api/v3/session", params: {
   :login    => @user,
   :password => @pass,
})['private_token']
```

Could someone please explain why this happens? I haven't seen any mention of hash expansion to keywords in the [Keyword arguments documentation](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/). And from what I've read the argument ordering should be: standard arguments, default arguments, keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`def post(url, send_json: false, success_only: true, **params)`

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20633975/1285164

now you can call

`self.post("#{@url}/api/v3/session", login: @user, password: @pass)`