# Strong parameter: issue with array on "permit" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

### The problem

> /app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => name, roles: [], (something here)

### The scenario

In `users_controller.rb`:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, roles: [])
```

### Diagnostics

- The problem happens when I access any page related to `users_controller.rb`;
- If I use `:roles => []` instead of `roles: []`, the error is the same;
- If I change `roles: []` for `:roles`, everything goes okay.

### Environment

I'm running on CentOS 6.5 with Rails 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects

Comment: I don't believe this is a dupe of that.  This is a syntax error in ruby, that was a question about how to use strong params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma is unexpected because it interprets `:name` as a hash key.  This is happening because Rails is seeing the hash `roles: []`.    Explicitly mark it as such

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, {roles: []})
```

Comment: As I said, I'm using Rails 4... Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826407/rails-3-multiple-select-with-has-many-through-associations) question wrong?

Comment: Ruby has two valid ways to interpret the parameters you're passing to `permit`, as a hash or as an array which contains a hash.  It seems to have chosen the former for some reason.  I'll admit myself surprised, but take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20633975/2483138) to dive into how Ruby interprets parameter lists.

Comment: In the answer linked, the parser correctly understands that the arguments are an array followed by a hash.  I suspect you would need to dive into the source code for the strong_params gem for more clarity