# Ruby parameters SyntaxError with varargs

Tags: ruby

```
    def a(b: 88, c: 97)
      puts b
      puts c
    end
```

The above code works. But,

```
def a(b: 88, c: 97, *c)
  puts b
  puts c
end
```

Throws a syntax error. Can anyone point me to the right documentation that explains it?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do, i.e. what is the expected value for `c` within the method when being called with different values?

Answer (score 5):

Positional arguments go first in a method signature. Named arguments go last.

This will work better, but you still have a duplicate parameter name, which is not allowed.

```
def a(*c, b: 88, c: 97)
  puts b
  puts c
end
# ~> -:1: duplicated argument name
# ~> def a(*c, b: 88, c: 97)
# ~>                    ^
```

Great answers with more info: [Mixing keyword with regular arguments in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20633412/125816)