# An argument that can be supplied in both positional and keyword ways?

Tags: ruby, arguments, keyword-argument, positional-parameter

In Python, a positional argument can always be supplied as a keyword argument (we're not digging into Python-C extensions where this may be false):

```py
def foo(bar=None):
    print(bar)

foo("aaa")
foo(bar="aaa")
```

I want to achieve the same effect as `bar` in Ruby. However neither `bar = nil` nor `bar: nil` work:

- `def foo bar = nil` is positional-only, and arguments passed as `foo(key: value)` will be collected into a Hash and provided as the next positional argument, while `foo(bar = value)` instead assigns to a local variable `bar` and passes it positionally (instead of matching the argument name).
- `def foo bar: nil` is keyword-only. There's no way to supply `bar` except in the form `f(bar: value)`

I'm afraid it's not possible in Ruby to have an argument that can be passed both positionally and keyword-ly. Is it?

I only need to work with Ruby 2.5 and later.

Comment: I highly recommend reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955936/1596460

Answer (score 1):

The closest you are going to get in Ruby is:

```
def foo(bar=nil, **kwargs)
  bar = bar || kwargs[:bar]
end
```

Which is not great since the method now takes any keyword argument.

Ruby does not allow you to duplicate a argument name:

```
irb(main):022:0> def foo(bar = nil, bar: nil)
irb(main):023:1> end
Traceback (most recent call last):
SyntaxError ((irb):22: duplicated argument name)
def foo(bar = nil, bar: nil)
```

And while this might be a nice feature in Python - its not Ruby-eske. In Ruby passing a hash to a method follows the same syntax as defining a hash - because that's exactly what you are doing.